# Vaadin7: Tracking whether a user is active (DOM Event Handler)

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin

We are currently porting our app to vaadin 7 and I want to track wether a user has been active during the last 30s or so.
We used to track user activity in a custom CommunicationManager, but since this class is deprecated, I figured we might have to try differently.

I created an extension that I extend the UI with.

For simplicity's sake let's say, we count clicking and keyboard usage as user activity:

```
// this is the extend method in the extension connector
@Override
protected void extend (ServerConnector target) {
  UIConnector uiConnector = (UIConnector) target;
  VUI uiWidget = uiConnector.getWidget();
  uiWidget.addDomHandler(this.keyPressed(), KeyPressEvent.getType());
  uiWidget.addDomHandler(this.mouseClicked(), ClickEvent.getType());
}
```

The extension will then schedule a timer that will call the server via RPC every 30s, but only if the user has been active.
This Timer works. What does not work is the DOM Events, they never seem to reach the Event Listeners I added.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your implementation, I would suggest you give [Refresher add-on](http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/26) a try. It works in similar manner but gives you more control regarding polling interval, server-side listener. Plus, you don't have to maintain it.

The other alternative would be taking advantage of Vaadin polling support (see https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using%20polling).

Comment: The refresher doesn't do the same thing. In fact the refresher is exactly what initiall y brought up the problem. We cannot track request activity of the session, when there is a refresher on a certain page. The users session would never time out, because the refresher keeps creating requests.